# `const` for local variables where possible is considered a good practice?

Tags: javascript, local-variables

I think that it is preferable to use `const` everywhere as possible, even for local variables, but my colleague thinks that `const` is only for top-level constants like a number of the planets in the solar system (hm). I just like the functional style or this is a commons sense?

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const

Comment: `const` does mean "this variable does not change", it does not mean "this variable is a global constant".

Comment: This is a matter of style and therefore off-topic for SO. (Personally, I'm a fan. I also know smart people I respect who aren't.)

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV If a local variable *is* constant for the lifetime of that variable, it would make sense to declare it with `const`. IMO, using `const` whenever possible makes code more readable, because you immediately know it's never going to be reassigned, which is one less thing you have to worry about while reading further code below.

Comment: @CertainPerformance but local variables mostly we will change. if not i agree const is preferable

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV - I used to think that. But if you try it, you'll probably be surprised just how many locals you have are unchanging references to objects. :-) Particularly if you keep functions short.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV in functional style you create a new variable instead of modifying existing one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the information

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich thanks for the information

Comment: Btw, the number of planets in the solar system changes much more often than some other values :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a common view expressed in several style guides, such as the popular [Airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#references) and [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-use-const-and-let) ones. So it is considered a good practice at least by some :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to change it, the `const` is apparently better as it protects you from accidently changing this variable.

Its also considered as good practice by one of the famous Node.js eslint guidelines created by Airbnb: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#references--prefer-const